# How to inject PersistenceContext during unit testing?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

This is my java class:

```
public class Finder {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "abc")
  EntityManager em;
  public boolean exists(int i) {
    return (this.em.find(Employee.class, i) != null);
  }
}
```

This is the unit test:

```
public class FinderTest {
  @Test public void testSimple() {
    Finder f = new Finder();
    assert(f.exists(1) == true);
  }
}
```

Testing fails with `NullPointerException` since `Finder.em` is not injected by anyone. How should I handle this situation properly? Does there any best practice exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without a container like Spring (or something like [Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/) - which is Spring based), you will have to inject the entity manager manually. In that case, you *could* use something like this as base class:

```
public abstract class JpaBaseRolledBackTestCase {
    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    protected EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createEntityManagerFactory() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PetstorePu");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        emf.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void beginTransaction() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @After
    public void rollbackTransaction() {   
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on *what* you want to test. When you have complex business logic in your `Finder` class you may want to mock the `EntityManager` - using a mocking framework like [EasyMock](http://easymock.org) or [Mockito](http://mockito.org) - in order to unit test that logic.

Now since that's not the case I suspect you want to test the persistency of the `Employee` entity (this is often referred to as *integration testing*). This requires the use of a database. To make testing easy and keep your tests portable you can use an in-memory database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) for this purpose. In order to start HSQLDB, create a persistence context and inject this context into your Finder class it's advisable to use an IoC framework like [Spring](http://springframework.org).

There are tons of tutorials on the internet that explain how to use JPA/Spring/HSQLDB. Take a look at this example project: [Integration testing with Maven 2, Spring 2.5, JPA, Hibernate, and HSQLDB](http://code.google.com/p/mvn2-spring-jpa/)

Comment: I have to do this injection "manually" in every unit test, right?

Comment: No Spring can parse the @PersistenceContext annotation and inject it into your Finder class. You just have to refer to the ApplicationContext from the FinderTest.

Answer (score 0):

Create another package-private constructor and add only EntityManager then call the other constructor for default behavior.

```java
@PersistentContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

private ManagementService managementService;

@Autowired
public SomeClass(ManagementService managementService) {
    this.managementService = managementService;
}

SomeClass(ManagementService managementService, EntityManager entityManager) {
    this(managementService);

    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```