# Injecting EntityManager in DAO's for in-memory DB unit/integration testing?

Tags: java, spring, testing, entitymanager

I have a small Spring web application, with the typical MVC Service DAO JPA/Hibernate Persistence Layer architecture. In production, I use a JTA-like persistence unit. The DAO is injected with an instance of the `EntityManager` via `@PersistenceContext` by the container. All is fine.

Now, I want to test my DAO implementations using an in-memory database (outside of a container on my local pc). I could manually create a RESOURCE_LOCAL based `EntityManager`. But how can I have it injected in my DAO implementations automatically?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807638/how-to-inject-persistencecontext-during-unit-testing) and it suggests that it is possible with Spring. But how?

Of course, for unit testing, I could use `new MyDAOImpl()` and inject the `EntityManager` myself, but later, I will want to test my services which are injected with DAO implementations. I would like to avoid having to wire everything myself... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our project, we define a different unit-testing-config.xml that has the datasource bean defined to point the in-memory database as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
                value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:/data/data.db" />
        <property name="user" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="240" />
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="1" />
</bean>
```

The normal `entityManagerFactory` defintion as follows will use the above `datasource` bean:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myDoctorPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>
```

And we run our `TestSuite` using the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations ={ "/spring-configuration/test-spring.xml" })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Creating the entity manager pointing to the in-memory database is not an issue. The issue is make sure this entity manager is injected in the annotated classes while running junit tests OUTSIDE of a a container. How to achieve this in your JUnit tests? Do you have a code example? Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by "outside of a container"?

Comment: When I run my JUnit tests from NetBeans, the code is not executed within Tomcat (for example). Hence, I can't use a JTA like persistence unit to wire my DAOs, Service etc... I believe I need to use a RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit for junit test and create the entity manager manually.

Comment: It doesn't need to run in tomcat. The spring container can be initialized during unit test using the above RunWith annotation. You may want to try this out and run a simple JUnit test to verify that the entity manager gets injected properly.

Comment: OK. I was trying to achieve this via Java configuration, but the EntityManagerFactory wouldn't be created. But, I found out why, I was missing an Hibernate dependency...